# PROBLEM: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, numpy, python-import, valueerror, opencsv

I'm conscious of the fact that this question has been asked a lot of times. Anyway, I still don't know how to solve my problem.

What I'm trying to do is to open a csv file in order to import number sequences. My main problem is the error "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" that appears because Python is not able to convert the '\n' into a float, obviously. Since I need to separate the sequences in order to distinguish the number sequences (that represent the value of pixels of an image) I don't know what to do.

This is the program I wrote:

```
import numpy
importmatplotlib.pyplot
%matplotlib inline
data_file=open(r"filepath\filename.csv",'r')

data_list=data_file.readlines()
all_values=data_list[0].split(',')
image_array=numpy.asfarray(all_values[1:]).reshape((28,28))
```

So I created a file and a list that reads it and distinguish sequences. My goal is now to plot a matrix 28x28 that should show a written number (I'm building a neural networks that learns to understand human written numbers) but, as I run the last coding line, I get that error.

An advice would be very much appreciated because I'm currently stuck here.

Comment: Look at `all_values` list.  Anything that isn't a number?  Get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure but the problem starts when you split it. Because after splitting it will convert into a list with all the elements bound in quotes i.e., converted to strings. So I think you need to convert them to float first.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `rstrip()` method to remove newlines.

Instead of `all_values=data_list[0].split(',')` use `all_values=data_list[0].rstrip().split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading a CSV file with any data, I highly recommend to use **[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html)**. This would help you to use the data with Neural Networks as well. ([Install Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/))

Below snippet will load the CSV into `Pandas` 2-dimensional data type called [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filepath\filename.csv')
```

If you're not familiar with **Pandas** to work further with this data type, just transform the `df` to a **NumPy** array.

```
df.to_numpy()  # This will return a 2D array.
```

Or, if you know the column name you need to derive.

```
df['column_name'].to_numpy() # This will return a 1D array.
```

Using Pandas you don't want to worry about carriage returns and line feeds. If you want to change the data type of a column;

```
df['column_name'].astype('float')
```